# mongoose populate with distinct field does not give the correct result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My query is as shown below :

```
DB.find({status:"placed"}).populate('category').distinct('category.mobile').exec((err,docs) =>{
    if(err) {
        console.log('error is '+ err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('doc length is '+ docs.length);
    }
})
```

Sample data is :

```
[  
   {  
      "status":"placed",
      "category":{  
         "mobile":9654356450
      }
   },
   {  
      "status":"placed",
      "category":{  
         "mobile":9428462849
      }
   }
]
```

But somehow `docs.length` value is not correct. So how to modify this query to give an accurate result?

Comment: You can put the conditions here to match only correct documents.

Comment: @ShivamPandey I think, i have mentioned the collection name and sub document name also and I have also mentioned the problem that I am facing .

Comment: Please provide some of the data sets stored in the collection.

Comment: @ShivamPandey I have updated the sample collections

Comment: @MrugeshThaker Well populate doesn't give the best result all the time. If you show the sample output then I can recommend you some better way to achieve this.